# How to make my text moving from right to left in php?

Tags: css, web, arabic-support

I have a site  which support Arabic  Languge and I need  to move the  text from right  to left ,I have tried
    dir="rtl" 
but  it doesn't work  any help please? thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

use direction and unicode-bidi

```css
div { direction:rtl; unicode-bidi:bidi-override; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<div>stack over flow</div>
</html>
```

or Refer this [article](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<p><span dir="rtl">ARABIC</span><span>aaaddd</span></p>
</html>
```